How to format HTML text so it wraps around keywords
So I have this code with a paragraph with keywords and text.
I need to make the format so that the keywords appear next to other, the text starts where the keywords end and then the text also wraps around the keywords.
I tried doing it with display: flex but I just couldn't figure out the way to get the desired outcome. Also the text on the line after the first one should have a small margin to the left, aka to not be in line with the start of the keywords.
I am here putting my code, an also a screenshot of how the desired outcome should be.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.


.paragraph {
  display: flex;
  width: 320px;
}

.keywords {
  display: flex;
}

.keywords .item {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.keywords .item::after {
  content: "-";
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
}
<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="keywords">
    <div class="item">KEYWORD 1</div>
    <div class="item">KEYWORD 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>



The correct format should look like this:


Take a look at display: inline-block

@phuzi I tried the code from @Meher Khurana 's answer that uses display: inline-block but unfortunately is not doing the correct formatting. I'm I doing something wrong?

Wrapping text around an element pretty much requires the use of float.
For this reason the "paragraph" wrapper cannot be display: flex as this negates the use of float. Here I have used inline-block instead.


.paragraph {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
}

.keywords {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}

.keywords .item {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.keywords .item::after {
  content: "-";
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="keywords">
    <div class="item">KEYWORD 1</div>
    <div class="item">KEYWORD 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>




Is there any way to add the small margin to the left of the text under the keywords?

Sure, just added margin-left: 1em...

Remove display: flex it isn't doing what you want it to do.
With display: inline you can get all elements to render inline one after the other.
Using a combination of positive and negative left margins you can emulate the hanging indent on the paragraph too.


.paragraph {
  width: 320px;
  margin-left: 2em; // indent the whole paragraph
}

.keywords {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -2em; // Push these back over to the left
}

.keywords .item {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.keywords .item::after {
  content: "-";
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.text {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline;
}
<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="keywords">
    <div class="item">KEYWORD 1</div>
    <div class="item">KEYWORD 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>



